# How could I define the "resource" for Token-based authentication in webapi.xml?

Tags: magento-2.1

I created a custom REST Web Service in Magento2.1 Community. In webapi.xml, I have so defined:

```
<route url="/api/updateProductPriceByID" method="POST">
    <service class="CompanyName\WebService\Api\ProductInterface" method="updateProductPriceByID"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="CompanyName_WebService::manage"/>
    </resources>
</route>
```

For Authentication, I created a Role and a User in Admin Panel:

```
Role Name: Webservice Role
User Name: wsuser
```

With this user, I can get Admin Token, Here is no problem.

```
Request: POST /V1/integration/admin/token
Response: 6f7jecvafar79nr61g76fbtukswighrp (for example)
```

And now I want to call this API with my Admin Token, I got error:

```
{"message":"Consumer is not authorized to access %resources","parameters":{"resources":"CompanyName_WebService::manage"}
```

How could solve this problem?
I think I did wrong with resources in webapi.xml.
But how could I define resources in webapi.xml?
Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should check if sent token correctly. With «Bearer», space between «Bearer» and token itself, without additional characters
   Ex:

> Authorization: Bearer 4fp6f4qw9mtu6jol198py75u5r2h3g4s

2. Make sure you created the ACL rules for CompanyName_WebService::manage resource and your used is granted to use this resource.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
       <acl>
           <resources>
               <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                   <resource id="CompanyName_WebService::manage" title="CompanyName WebService" sortOrder="51"/>
               </resource>
           </resources>
       </acl>
   </config>
   ```

You can use 3 difference options for resource node in webapi.xml: self, anonymous, Magento resource (like Magento_Tax::manage_tax).

> A guest or anonymous is a special permission that doesn’t need to be defined in acl.xml (and will not show up in the permissions tree in the Magento Admin). It just indicates that the current resource in webapi.xml can be accessed without the need for authentication.
>
> Similarly, self is a special access used if you already have an authenticated session with the system. Self access enables a user to access resources they own. For example, GET /V1/customers/me fetches the logged-in customer’s details. This is typically useful for JavaScript-based widgets.

Magento resource requires valid ACL rules for the user.

You can find more in the documentation http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication.html#acl-webapi-relation

Comment: You are right. After creating a ACL rules in acl.xml, the api works fine with token! Thank you!